# How to reload a lightning page after clicking on a custom button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning

I am using a custom button having VF behaviour on contail detail page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactController" action="{!logrecord}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<script type = "text/javascript">
alert(document.location.href);
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

The action logrecord is a page reference method return type which navigates to an internal URL.

Once I click the VF page custom button, How can I refresh the contact detail page? I tried with window object and DOM element as well but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Typically from VF page **pagination** is the preferred way to go. But currently there is a weird bug in lightning that prevents reflection of data updates on UI after pagination.
For more info, please look into below link.
[Data updates are not reflected in UI after a Visualforce+Apex update in Lightning Experience](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU&title=data-not-updated-in-ui-after-an-apex-update-in-lightning-experience)

Thanks